# Ansible playbook error

Tags: ansible-playbook

Hi I have just started learning ansible. I am trying to write playbook as:

**vpc-setup.yml** which including

```yaml
hosts: localhost
connection: local
gather_facts: False
tasks:
 - name: Import VPC Variables
   include_vars: vars/vpc_setup.md

 - name: Create vprofile VPC
   ec2_vpc_net:
    name: "{{vpc_name}}"
    cidr_block: "{{vpcCidr}}"
    region: "{{region}}"
    dns_hostnames: yes
    tenancy: default
    state: "{{state}}"
    register: vpcout
```

the error is coming in 1st line:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all'
ERROR! A playbook must be a list of plays, got a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'> instead

The error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/ansible-aws-vpc/vpc-setup.yml': line 1, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


hosts: localhost
^ here
```

---

**Kindly help**

Comment: I have edited to add code blocks. On Stack Exchange, YAML will be formatted as Markdown and be unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

An Ansible playbook is one YAML document containing a list of plays, possibly more than one.   Because it is a list, the outer part of the document needs YAML list notation, so `-`.

```yaml
- name: VPC for thing
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
```

The rest of the play follows.

More examples in Ansible's [guide introducing playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html). Pay close attention to indentation, and the outer `-` indicating a YAML list.

---

Bonus tips:

`name` keyword on plays documents a purpose. Keep name short, 50 characters or less.

Delete `connection: local` at the play level. If run against a pattern with multiple hosts, it will run many times, which is unlikely what you want. [Implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) is already local, or you can set the connection plugin per host or group at the inventory level.

Comment: Thanks John. I will try what you explained. Can we have a direct communication. I am eager to learn and i really need someone who can guide. Hope you understand.